# Python crashes when I put process.join in script when using multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.4, python-multiprocessing

I have been researching multiprocessing and came upon an example of it on a website. However, when I try to run that example on my MacBook retina, nothing happens. The following was the example:

```
import random
import multiprocessing


def list_append(count, id, out_list):
 """
 Creates an empty list and then appends a 
 random number to the list 'count' number
 of times. A CPU-heavy operation!
 """
 for i in range(count):
     out_list.append(random.random())

if __name__ == "__main__":
 size = 10000000 # Number of random numbers to add
 procs = 2 # Number of processes to create

# Create a list of jobs and then iterate through
# the number of processes appending each process to
# the job list 
jobs = []
for i in range(0, procs):
    out_list = list()
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=list_append, 
         args=(size, i, out_list))
    jobs.append(process)

# Start the processes (i.e. calculate the random number lists)      
for j in jobs:
    j.start()

# Ensure all of the processes have finished
for j in jobs:
j.join()

print ("List processing complete.")
```

As it turns out after I put a print statement in the 'list_append' function, nothing printed, so the problem is actually not the `j.join()` but rather the `j.start()` bit.

Comment: why do you have separate loops for creating, starting and join of the processes?

Comment: @Corn3lius - I literally just copied and pasted from an example that I found online, I have otherwise tried to take them out of the loop, however, I encounter the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a process with `multiprocessing.Process`, you prepare a sub-function to be run in a different process asynchronously. The computation starts when you call the `start` method. The join method waits for the computation to be done. So if you just start the process and do not wait for the to complete (or `join`) nothing will happen as the process will be killed when your program exit.

Here, one issue is that you are not using an object sharable in `multiprocessing`. When you use a common `list()`, each process will use a different list in memory. The local process will be cleared when the processes exit and the main list will be empty. If you want to be able to exchange processes between data you should use a `multiprocessing.Queue`:

```
import random
import multiprocessing


def list_append(count, id, out_queue):
    """
    Creates an empty list and then appends a
    random number to the list 'count' number
    of times. A CPU-heavy operation!
    """
    for i in range(count):
        out_queue.put((id, random.random()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    size = 10000   # Number of random numbers to add
    procs = 2   # Number of processes to create

    # Create a list of jobs and then iterate through
    # the number of processes appending each process to
    # the job list
    jobs = []
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for i in range(0, procs):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=list_append,
                                          args=(size, i, q))
        process.start()
        jobs.append(process)

    result = []
    for k in range(procs*size):
        result += [q.get()]

    # Wait for all the processes to finish
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

    print("List processing complete. {}".format(result))
```

Note that this code can hang quite easily if you do not compute correctly the number of results sent back in `out_queue`.
If you try to retrieve too many results, `q.get` will wait for an extra result that will never come. If you do not retrieve all the result from `q`, your processes will freeze as the `out_queue` will be full, and `out_queue.put` will not return. Your processes will thus never exit and you will not be able to join them.
If your computation are independent, I strongly advise to look at higher level tools like `Pool` or even more robust third party library like `joblib` as it will take care of these aspects for you. ([see this answer for some insights on `Process` vs `Pool`/`joblib`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39896352/2642845))

I actually reduced the number `size` as the program become to slow if you try to put to many objects in a `Queue`. If you need to pass a lot of small object, try passing all of them in one batch:

```
import random
import multiprocessing


def list_append(count, id, out_queue):
    a = [random.random() for i in range(count)]
    out_queue.put((id, a))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    size = 10000   # Number of random numbers to add
    procs = 2   # Number of processes to create
    jobs = []
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for i in range(0, procs):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=list_append,
                                          args=(size, i, q))
        process.start()
        jobs.append(process)
    result += [q.get() for _ in range(procs)]
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()
    print("List processing complete.")
```

Comment: I added a little print statement after the `j.join()` in your first program, and it has been running for the past 20 mins without IDLE printing anything, any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: This code is subject to somme deadlocks that can keep the code hanging forever. You should make sure that you retrieve the right amount of results from the queue (If you try to retrieve, more, it will hang). If you do not retrieve enough result from the queue, the queue might be Full and also keep your Processes from exiting. To debug, you can use print statement after `result += [q.get()]` and `out_queue.put((id, random.random()))` to see what causes a freeze in yoru program.

Comment: I put print statements after the `result += [q.get()]` and `out_queue.put((id, random.random()))` but nothing printed in IDLE at all.

Comment: That either means that your processes did not started or that you have an issue with the line `random.random`. Try putting ones instead of random. If this is related to random, it might be os specific and I don't know what can be the cause.

Comment: This code work for me on macOS Sierra python2.7 and 3.5.

Comment: I just figured out that the problem is actually the '.start()' bit, since the function actually isn't even running.

Comment: Do you run this code from a file or from an interactive terminal? This is really weird if you do not have any errors showing up. Check that the processes are alive after start. Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I am running this code from IDLE, which I think is an interactive terminal. I am using python version 3.4.4. As for checking the processes are alive after start, how do I do that?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.is_alive) to check if a process is alive. (this is the first result from google)   
You should try launching the program with command lines `python ${name_your_file}.py` from the terminal to be sure it is not because of some interpreter issue (it is not easy to pickle interactive definition of function).

Comment: To debug further you can try to use `from multiprocessing import util` and then `util.log_to_stderr(5)` at the beginning of your file. It should print information about the processes when they are started.